# Multiple paths for the same route?

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to have a route `@route()` with multiple targets?

Maybe something like this:

`@route "article", paths: [ "/post/:post_id", "/url/with/slugs/:post_id" ]`

Right now, I have two different routes, a "real" one and another that redirects to the "real" one... Maybe there is something more straight forward?

Comment: no currently its not available...